# I need to calculate progress percentage in Excel for a project

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to see the progress percentage of work done. If today's date is greater than it should show "100%" If Today's date is less than End Date it should show the percentage of progress.
I have tried this code.

```
IF(AND(C3<D3,D3>TODAY()),(C3/D3), 100%)
```

C3= Start Date

D3= End Date

[image: Please refer to the screenshot below]

Comment: `C3/D3` doesn't make sense. What is the expected result here?

Comment: Is the work done based on days or some actual set of tasks?

Comment: It is based on dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
=IF(TODAY()<=C3,0,IF(TODAY()>=D3,1,(TODAY()-C3+1)/(D3-C3+1)))
```

[image]

---

Or just maths:

```
=MAX((MIN(TODAY(),D3)-C3+1)/(D3-C3+1),0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really helped. :)